# How to add more eggs from the command line?

Tags: python, buildout

My buildout.cfg looks like this :

```
[eggs]   
recipe = zc.recipe.egg   
eggs =
  package1
  package2
```

I would like to be able to add more eggs on the command line when I run buildout. It works well with one egg with:

> bin/buildout eggs:eggs+=package3

but I did not find any syntax to add more than one package. None of these are working:

> bin/buildout eggs:eggs+=package3 eggs:eggs+=package4
>
> bin/buildout "eggs:eggs+=package3 package4"
>
> bin/buildout "eggs:eggs+=package3:package4"

with variations of  : , ; and \n as a seprator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildout only takes newlines as separators when merging `+=` and `-=` options. You'll have to insert those newlines.

Bash lets you insert newlines on the command line within quoted strings:

```
$ bin/buildout "eggs:eggs+=package3
> package4
> "
```

You simply press `ENTER` after `package3` and you can insert newlines, until you enter a closing `"` quote.